# PHP Header Location adding current anchor during second redirect

Tags: php, forms, redirect, header, submit

I'm submitting a form to itself with an anchor added to the URL so that when there are errors, the form is guaranteed to be in the viewport, here's a simplified example...

```
<form id="my_form" action="/form_link/#my_form" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

When `/form_link/` receives the form post, it processes it, when there are errors it just continues loading the page again and shows the errors.

However when the post is successful it redirects to a different page using...

```
header('Location: /another_link/');
die;
```

The problem is that when I end up at the redirected link, the URL is actually...

```
/another_link/#my_form
```

instead of the expected...

```
/another_link/
```

I'm at a loss, the anchor is being added after the fact, so I have nothing to strip it from.  How can I prevent this behaviour?

---

**EDIT:** Could the reason possibly be because nothing has yet been output to the browser between the form submit and the redirection?  Is there anyway to clear whatever is in the header that's maintaining the anchor target?

---

**EDIT 2:** The headers that have already been sent as reported by `headers_sent()` are:

```
[0] => X-Powered-By: ZendServer 6.3.0
[1] => Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
[2] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
[3] => Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
[4] => Pragma: no-cache
[5] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: **REMOVED**
[6] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
[7] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
```

So I don't see anything in there that would affect follow up uses?!?!

Comment: Just add hash to location URL which will produce something like this: `/some_link/#`. Other way is to do some URL rewrite rule.

Comment: @Poldas Tried the empty hash `#` at the end, had no effect.  And with regard to rewrite, it seems ridiculous to have to rely on apache to do that kind of work for me, I'd rather understand where the header is maintaining the anchor.  I have a feeling it's because nothing is output to the browser prior to the redirect.

Comment: @user1844933 I'm sorry, I have no idea what that's in reference to.

Comment: @oucil Have you tried with full path location? Is there any chance that headers are sent before of secont redirect?

Comment: @Poldas I've just updated the question with details about already sent headers, no luck

Comment: @user1844933 Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: @Poldas ...Also, fully qualified URL made no diff either :(

Comment: @oucil I am neutral regarding this question not for + or - ...

Comment: @oucil can you provide PHP code that makes redirect? I'll check it in my enviroment.

Comment: @oucil wish u all the best to get solution.... u may start bounty for this question

Comment: @Poldas what's up there is essentially the essence, unfortunately I can't post more, it's part of a very large OOP project, I'm just trying to clean up minor annoyances, of which this one has been bugging me for quite some time ;)

Comment: @user1844933 Sorry, it came in at same time you commented and a -1 on a new question sends potential commenters away, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor is not sent to the server as part of the request; PHP has no knowledge of it. What you are seeing is client side (browser) behaviour. I just tested with other HTTP responses (301, 303, 304) and the result is the same.

I would suggest using JavaScript to scroll down to the form in the event of an error, instead of relying on the URL.

Comment: That makes a whole lot more sense, not what I was hoping for but something to work with now, thanks.